# Why does using a binding an attribute directive seem to call a function assigned to that binding so many times?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have the following button rendered in a modal:

```
<button class="ui blue compact tiny labeled icon button" [test-case-view-modal]="getSelectedTestCase()"
(save)="updateTestCaseExecuteStatus($event)" (close)="onCloseTestCaseModal()"  (click)="isShowOverlay = true"
[is-execute-test-run]="true" [disabled]="selectedTestCases.length == 0">
<i class="icon dropdown"></i>
  Run
</button>
```

The component is used like so:

```
<work-item-modal-testcase [model]="model" [hidden]="subMenu != 'testcase'"></work-item-modal-testcase>
```

The actual component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'work-item-modal-testcase',
  directives: [TestCaseViewModalDirective],
  template: `

    <style>
      .passed { background-color: #c2e6c2; color: #ffffff; }
      .failed { background-color: #c80f00; color: #ffffff; }
      .in-completed { background-color: #969696; color: #ffffff; }
      .blocked { background-color: #ffd800; color: #ffffff; }

    </style>

    <div class="ui right aligned fluid container">
      <button class="ui blue compact tiny labeled icon button" [test-case-view-modal]="getSelectedTestCase()"
        (save)="updateTestCaseExecuteStatus($event)" (close)="onCloseTestCaseModal()" (click)="isShowOverlay = true"
        [is-execute-test-run]="true" [disabled]="selectedTestCases.length == 0">
        <i class="icon dropdown"></i>
        Run
      </button>
      <button class="ui blue compact tiny labeled icon button" [test-case-view-modal]="sampleTestCase"
        (save)="createTestCase($event)" (close)="onCloseTestCaseModal()" (click)="isShowOverlay = true">
        <i class="icon plus"></i>
        Test Case
      </button>
      <button class="ui blue compact tiny right labeled icon button">
        <i class="icon dropdown"></i>
        Actions
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    <div class="ui fluid container">
      <table class="ui very compact small selectable celled table">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>
              <div class="fitted massive checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox">
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>Test Case</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Execute status</th>
            <th>Configuration</th>
            <th>Hrs</th>
            <th>Component</th>
            <th>Assigned</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th class="center aligned"><i class="blue edit icon"></i></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="#tc of model.testCases">
            <td>
              <div class="huge checkbox"><input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleTestCaseSelected($event, tc.id)"></div>
            </td>
            <td>{{ tc.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ tc.status.name }}</td>
            <td [class.passed]="tc.executeStatus === 'Passed'"
                [class.failed]="tc.executeStatus === 'Failed'"
                [class.in-completed]="tc.executeStatus === 'In Completed'"
                [class.blocked]="tc.executeStatus === 'Blocked'">
              <span *ngIf="tc.executeStatus"> {{ tc.executeStatus }} </span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ tc.effort }}</td>
            <td> <span *ngFor="#cmp of tc.components"> {{ cmp.name }} </span></td>
            <td> <span *ngFor="#assigner of tc.assigned"> {{ assigner.name }} </span></td>
            <td>{{ tc.start }}</td>
            <td>{{ tc.end }}</td>
            <td class="center aligned">
              <i class="blue edit link icon" [test-case-view-modal]="tc"
                (save)="testCaseService.update($event)" (close)="onCloseTestCaseModal()" (click)="isShowOverlay = true"></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="ui dimmer page" [class.active]="isShowOverlay"></div>
  `
})
class WorkItemModelTestcaseComponent {
  @Input() model: WorkItem;
  // FIXME: workaround for Semantic UI multiple modal: show overlay for disabled lower layer modal.
  private isShowOverlay: boolean;
  private sampleTestCase: SampleTestCase;
  private selectedTestCases: string[] = [];

  constructor(private testCaseService: TestCaseService) {
    this.onCloseTestCaseModal();
  }

  createTestCase(testCase: TestCase) {
    this.model.testCases.push(this.testCaseService.create(testCase));
  }

  onCloseTestCaseModal() {
    this.isShowOverlay = false;
    this.sampleTestCase = new SampleTestCase();
  }

  // TODO: sample code for getting first selected TestCase, or first testCase if Nothing is selected
  getSelectedTestCase(): TestCase {
    console.log("getSelectedTestCase => model => ", this.model);
    let firstSelectedId = this.selectedTestCases[0];
    return firstSelectedId
      ? _.head(_.filter(this.model.testCases, (x) => { return x.id === firstSelectedId; }))
      : this.model.testCases.length > 0 ? this.model.testCases[0] : null;
  }
  toggleTestCaseSelected(event, testCaseId: string) {
    //console.log("toggleTestCaseSelected", testCaseId, event.target.checked, !event.target.checked, event);
    let indexTc = this.selectedTestCases.indexOf(testCaseId);
    if (-1 === indexTc) {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        this.selectedTestCases.push(testCaseId);
      };
    } else {
      if (!event.target.checked) {
        this.selectedTestCases.splice(indexTc, 1);
      };
    };
    console.log("this.selectedTestCases", this.selectedTestCases);
  }

  //-------------------------------------------------
  updateTestCaseExecuteStatus(data: TestCase) {
    console.log("updateTestCaseExecuteStatus");
    this.getSelectedTestCase().executeStatus = data.executeStatus;
  }
}
```

Basically, I use this button to open a *new* modal on the screen on click.  I've created a directive that listens to the hosts (click) and loads the *new* modal next to the location of the click:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[test-case-view-modal]',
  inputs: [
    'testCase'
  ],
  providers: [
    TestCaseService
  ],
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick()'
  }
})
export class TestCaseViewModalDirective {
  @Input('test-case-view-modal') testCase: TestCase;
  @Output() save: EventEmitter<TestCase> = new EventEmitter<TestCase>();
  @Output() close: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() start: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input('is-execute-test-run') isExecuteTestRun: boolean;

  constructor(private loader: DynamicComponentLoader, private appRef: ApplicationRef,
      private _testCaseService: TestCaseService) {
        console.log('TestCaseViewModalDirective :: () ');
      }

  onClick() {
    if (this.start) {
      this.start.next(true);
    };
    let appEleRef = this.appRef['_rootComponents'][0].location;
    let bindings = Injector.resolve([
      provide(TestCase, {
          useValue: this.testCase
      })
    ]);
    return this.loader.loadNextToLocation(TestCaseViewComponent, appEleRef, bindings).then(testCaseViewModalRef => {
      let testCaseModelComponent = <TestCaseViewComponent>testCaseViewModalRef.instance;
      testCaseModelComponent.isExecuteTestRun = this.isExecuteTestRun;
      testCaseModelComponent.closeEvent.subscribe(_ => {
      testCaseViewModalRef.dispose();
        this.close.emit(_);
      });
      testCaseModelComponent.saveEvent.subscribe(_ => {
        this.save.emit(_);
      });
      return testCaseViewModalRef;
    });
  }
}
```

The property binding for the directive calls this function:

```
  getSelectedTestCase(): TestCase {
    console.log("getSelectedTestCase => model => ", this.model);
    let firstSelectedId = this.selectedTestCases[0];
    return firstSelectedId
      ? _.head(_.filter(this.model.testCases, (x) => { return x.id === firstSelectedId; }))
      : this.model.testCases.length > 0 ? this.model.testCases[0] : null;
  }
```

When I load the *first* modal, the output I see from the log message inside the function shows the function gets called several times:

```
=> triggered change detection
work-items.ts:34 WorkItemModalDirective :: open()
work-items.ts:34 new work item =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 TestCaseViewModalDirective :: () 
work-items.ts:34 TestCaseViewModalDirective :: () 
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
work-items.ts:34 getSelectedTestCase => model =>  WorkItem {id: "0e2f734e-1d08-481a-b12a-ebf75a07be0d", issueLink: "XX1211", summary: "Newly added work item", description: undefined, project: Object…}
```

My question that I cannot figure out is why this function gets called so many times upon rendering the button from the first modal (by showing the component)?  I've added logging to add ngOnChange which shows only one change is happening to the parent component (the first modal), and the directive is only loaded once.

Answer (score 1):

As mentiond by @kemsky functions (and properties and getters) bound to in the view are evaluated every time change detection happens.

The Angular team discourages binding to functions. Instead store the result in a property and bind to that property.

There is also a common error with bound functions. If your function looks like

```
someFunc() {
  return ['a'];
}
```

Angular will throw

> Expression has changed after it was checked.

because in `devMode` Angular runs one additional change detection cycle after each normal change detection cycle and expects the model not to change in between because this indicates that change detection itself causes the model to change which will make your application behave weirdly in production.

An alternative way to storing the value to a property is to set a different change detection strategy for your component

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

and then tell Angular when to run change detection on your component.
For more details see http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

> Angular executes template expressions more often than we think. They can be called after every keypress or mouse move. Expressions should finish quickly or the user experience may drag, especially on slower devices. Consider caching values computed from other values when the computation is expensive.

[link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#quick-execution)